# Mongoengine... query something not in a ListField?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine

for example..

```
class Page(Document)
    tags = ListField(StringField())
```

In this case, we can find out a value in the tags list like this.

```
Page.objects(tags='coding')
```

if tags are like ['coding', 'x', 'y'], then the document will be matched...

but My question is how I can find out the value not in the listfield.

my incorrect code would be..

```
Page.objects(tags!='coding')
```

or

```
Page.objects(tags__not = 'coding')
```

or

```
Page.objects(tags__not__in = 'coding')
```

but.. they don't simply work..

**how can I query a document that does not have a given value in a ListField?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To find any pages that don't have the tags coding use the [$nin](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24nin) operator:

```
Page.objects(tags__nin=['coding'])
```

Answer (score 1):

I would skip using the build-in mongo syntax on this one and just use a raw query:

```
Page.objects(__raw__={"tags" : {"$ne" : ['coding']}})
```

As query get more complicated, your going to wish you set it up like this.